# How to implement `using` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make something like this (similar to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)):

```
using("content/jquery.js");

$("div").fadeOut();
```

So if `content/jquery.js` is not on a `script` in the `head` I would like to load it and continue the execution after it loads.

Is it possible to implement this or something similar? Note: I could have more than 1 `using`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called script loaders.

You can take a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), which behaves in a very similar way:

```
require(["helper/util"], function() {
    //This function is called when scripts/helper/util.js is loaded.
});
```

There's also [LabJS](http://labjs.com/) and [ControlJS](http://stevesouders.com/controljs/), which are more focused on async script loading rather than dependencies, but may be worth checking out. Also in this category, our very own @jAndy's [SupplyJS](https://github.com/jAndreas/Supply).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript):

```
$.getScript('test.js', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: +1 good answer which I forgot about. It's funny though because in the example the OP is trying to load jQuery, while this uses jQuery. But you have to have some script that starts it all, it just depends on your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, but didn't know what he wanted.  there are [other ways](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml) or [other ways](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) to load JS files dynamically, but the jQuery offers a callback, so it's probably better.

Comment: Looking at the source code it seems `getScript` inject the script on the `head` and uses `onload` event on the `script` to execute the callback function... Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the functions you'll be calling ahead of time you can use `typeof` to check for their presence:

```
if (typeof($) == 'function') {
  // Code here that uses jQuery
} else {
  // Something else here that loads the script.
}
```

If you're not certain what functions you'll be using you probably want to retrieve a list of the script elements and check them.  Something more along these lines:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

for (var i = 0, l = scripts.length; i < l; ++i) {
  if (scripts[i].src == myVal) {
    // do something here
  } else {
    // wait for the script to load, or just leave off the else.
  }
}
```

Are the two approaches I can think of off the top of my head.